# How to remove row from Qtableview and SQLite using with QSqlTableModel?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5, qtableview, qtsql

Below is the code i am using:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
import sqlite3


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("tableview.ui", self)
        self.show()
        
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        db.setDatabaseName("book.db")
        db.open()

        DBModel = QSqlQueryModel()
        DBModel.setQuery("select * from card",db)
        self.tableView.setModel(DBModel)


        self.dbmodel = DBModel
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.removeRow)

                
    def removeRow(self):
        tmodel = QSqlTableModel()
        selected = self.tableView.selectedIndexes()

        rows = set(index.row() for index in selected)
        rows = list(rows)
        rows.sort()
        first = rows[0]

        tmodel.deleteRowFromTable(first)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.exec_()
```

This code is unable to delete selected row in the Qtableview and SQLite. I am trying use QSqlTableModel, getting no error but its not working not deleting the row. I missed something. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using QSqlQueryModel as a model for the table, instead of directly using QSqlTableModel?

Comment: No, Actually i searched on internet and  Just i tried. Is it possible to do it with QSqlTableModel directly without using QSqlQueryModel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `deleteRowFromTable` was useless, because you didn't select any table; note that you should not use that function anyway (from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#deleteRowFromTable):

> This is a low-level method that operates directly on the database and should not be called directly. Use removeRow() or removeRows() to delete values.

You should use [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html) instead of QSqlQueryModel. Remember that if any change happens from code, the model requires to be repopulated using [`select()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#select) in order to the view to be correctly updated.

```py
class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        # ...

        DBModel = QSqlTableModel()
        DBModel.setTable("card")
        DBModel.select()
        self.tableView.setModel(DBModel)

        self.dbmodel = DBModel
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.removeRow)

    def removeRow(self):
        selected = self.tableView.selectedIndexes()

        rows = set(index.row() for index in selected)
        rows = list(rows)
        rows.sort()
        first = rows[0]

        self.dbmodel.removeRow(first)
        self.dbmodel.select()
```

Comment: So, here is no need to use  remove rows in REVERSE order? am i correct?

Comment: No, you're not. Depending on the edit strategy (and, I believe, the way the database backend works), you might get inconsistent results. Keep removing the rows in reverse order, it's always safer and has no contraindications.

Comment: Means, for example, there is no need to use reverse order If remove single row? and if remove multiple rows, there is need to use reverse order?

Comment: If you remove a single row, why would you need sorting?